# Is there an easy way of reformatting this in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to copy a table from a pdf into excel but the formatting is lost during the copy and paste.

The original table looks like:

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

And it pastes to:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Is there a built-in or easy way of reformatting this into the original format? i.e. get the i+3n values in column i, for increasing n.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, this should do the trick.

```
=OFFSET($G$1,COLUMNS($G1:G1)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I think this is going in the opposite direction to what I want. I want to separate into 3 columns and currently have it all in one column.

Comment: @Agustin hows that looking now?

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: ROW and COLUMN are awesome for transforming data sets, I have found when using larger data, it is better to use INDEX rather than OFFSET. INDEX seems to be much quicker. +1 I think OFFSET must be volatile.