# I have a column of test (exam) questions with answers. How do I convert them into multiple rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 1 column in excel file which has the following data in the cells (1 row, per cell):

```
1. Question1:
A. Answer1;
B. Answer2;
C. Answer3;
D. Answer4.
2. Question2:
A. Answer1;
B. Answer2;
C. Answer3;
D. Answer4.
3. Question3:
A. Answer1;
B. Answer2;
C. Answer3;
D. Answer4.
```

... and so on

I am trying to convert it to the following format - in the separate excel rows and cells:

```
1. Question1: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
2. Question1: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
3. Question1: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
```

Could you please advise how can I get this? The column is quite big. I am failing to write the formula that would increment by 5 when auto-expanding the cells.

Comment: Is it always 4 answers?

Comment: One part of the tests has 4 answers. Another 3 answers. No other variations

Comment: considering its not a set size i would use VBA, i answered similar here with a formula with a fixed length if you want to go that route
https://superuser.com/questions/1517981/is-there-an-easy-way-of-reformatting-this-in-excel/1517987#1517987

Comment: @GeoDrawkcab,, I think your post needs few corrections,, `1.` with source data each Answer ends with Semi colon but in output it don't have ,,, `2.` as per my knowledge this could better solve by using Macro  (VBA code),, so please [Edit] your post and be specific all about need and if need Macro then add TAG , `VBA` to the question.

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for the clarification. I edited the post. As for the VBA code or Macro, I am not sure which way to go, maybe with the simple formula could be solved. Sorry for my dilatancy

Comment: @SQLTemp thanks. In that example, I remade a bit the formula and it worked only for the first row. But the second row and on, it gets the random data - don't maintain the QUESTION as a first cell for the row
Additionally, I can easily separate the 3-answers and 4-answers questions, so if I get it working formulas, I can run them separately for each format

Comment: How many times do you want to repeat each sequence?  In your example, you show the first sequence repeating three times.  will that always be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table of results is incorrect, and you really want to have the different questions on each line, as:

```
1. Question1: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
2. Question2: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
3. Question3: | A. Answer1; | B. Answer2; | C. Answer3; | D. Answer4.
```

then you could use Power Query

- Add a custom column

  - test the first character in the string

    - If it is a number then this is a question and copy from Column, otherwise leave it empty *null*
- Add a second custom column

  - If first character is not a number then this is an answer, so copy it over
- Select the Question column and `Fill Down`
- Group by question
- Convert the resultant table column into a List of answers

  - Add Column Formula: `=Table.Column([Grouped],"Custom.1")`
- Expand the list using `tab` for a delimiter by clicking on the double headed arrow at the top of the column.
- Then split the list column on the `tab` into new columns

Except for entering the various added column formulas, this can all be done from the UI, but here is the

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if (try Text.InferNumberType(Text.Start([Column1],1)) otherwise false) = false then null else [Column1]),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom.1", each if (try Text.InferNumberType(Text.Start([Column1],1)) otherwise false) = false then [Column1] else null),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Column1=text, Index=number, Custom=text, Custom.1=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom.1", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Custom.1")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Custom.1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(tab)"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(tab)", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1.1", "Custom.1.2", "Custom.1.3", "Custom.1.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1.1", type text}, {"Custom.1.2", type text}, {"Custom.1.3", type text}, {"Custom.1.4", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]